# How to have different shortcuts open different workspace in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tend to use vscode for doing a lot of my coding these days. I have a workspace for vhdl, python, and latex. I sometimes have to switch between them several times a day. I wonder if there's a way, such as creating a shortcut, that would automatically launch vscode with the workspace loaded so that I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a keybinding like:

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",         // whatever keybindings you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "code -n '<absolute path to folder>'\u000D" }
},
```

It just sends that line to the terminal, see [Core CLI Options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options).  Replace with the path to your other workspace folders.  The path separators may have to be double escaped like `C:\\Users\\Mark\\etc...`.   The `\u000D` is a return so it runs immdeiately.